# Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account on Android - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm looking at the following doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Step 2 says to not go past FirebaseAuth.signInWith and because of that I'm getting a NullPointerException in Step 4 at mAuth.getCurrentUser() because there are no logged in users.

When I log off from the app I use FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

My questions is: is it possible to link 2 auth providers (in my app Google and email/password) after the user logs off from whichever auth method was used first. If I don't do FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() while logging off the application will detect the user and go straight in the next time I start it. That means it will never give the option to choose another provider.

The logic I'm looking for:

1. Register and sign in with email/pass combination.
2. Log off.
3. Use Google Sign in (account associated with the same email as in step1)
4. Instead of creating a new account in Firebase Console with a different UID link it to the existing one.

And the other way around:

1. Sign in with Google account (new Firebase Console account is created)
2. Log off.
3. Register email/password and log in.
4. Instead of creating a new account in Firebase Console with a different UID link it to the existing one.

So far I've been using email instead of UID and checking the database for the presence of the email before creating a new Firebase account. Now I'd like to switch to using UID to implement security rules more efficiently.